# How much extra security do the Host part of a mysql user account provide?

Tags: mysql

MySQL users have a username and a `Host` associated with them, so usually you'd identify the user by `'user'@'host'`. The host part is there to assure only clients which connect from that specific host are allowed, even if they happen to have the correct username and password. It also allows two users with the same username, but from different hosts, to exist on the same MySQL server.

But wouldn't it be possible to spoof the host name of the client, so that I claim to be coming from the host of my victim? Do the `'host'` part of a user really provide any extra security?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The client does not "present" anything related to `host`.

The server sees an incoming connection from a given IP and  this is resolved by your `mysql` server and then compared to `host`,  so it is not obvious to spoof. Your DNS resolution would need to have been modified first (or upstream DNS servers would need to have been hacked).

So yes,  there is extra security provided by `host`.

Comment: This answer is essentially correct but omits the fact that MySQL uses forward-confirmed reverse DNS, so the ip-to-hostname lookup is followed by a hostname-to-ip lookup to ensure the original value can be found, so *both* reverse *and* forward DNS must be compromised to thwart this mechanism.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/host-cache.html

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: yes, correct. Since these two DNSes are usually different (and often handled by different entities (PTR by the ARIN-authorized one and direct by the organization) it gets even more difficult.